# Extend output of git log

Tags: git, terminal

I did

```
git log --graph --all -10
```

in a command line terminal, i.e. listed the last 10 commits. When I reached the end of the listed commits, I realized I want to see more, say I want to extend the output of `git log` by 5 more commits. Is this possible interactively, or is it mandatory I quit the current `git log` and do a new `git log --graph --all -15`?

Comment: No, this is not possible interactively, yes you would have to redo a longer `log`. Maybe do a longer log in the first place but use a pager to present the results?

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks. As far as I understand the concept "pager" (just heard it for the first time, had to google), the output that I get after `git log --graph --all` is already "paged" (if that's the correct word): I can scroll up and down in it only by using the up-/down-keys, and interrupt the output by pressing <kbd>q</kbd> at any time.

Comment: Yes but there are alternative pagers out there. Check `git log --graph --all | less` for example to see if it fits your needs. You can navigate through it then when you close it didn't clog your terminal.

Comment: @RomainValeri Both of `git log --graph --all | less` and `git log --graph --all | more` are less satisfactory than the simple `git log --graph --all`. I miss output coloring and also (which might be interesting) it doesn't show to which commits the branches point. I didn't try out other pagers yet, and I am actually satisfied with the default pager. (And you are right after all: Why should I not do `git log --graph --all`? Since I can handle the output easily.)

Comment: Yes, I've had similar feelings about `less/more` and I don't use them either. Switching between different log aliases suited to the most frequent needs does the job for me.

Comment: `less` will retain color as long as it's run with the `-R` option or similar. Git will also export `LESS` (env var for `less`'s options) setting as `FRSX` or whatever is compiled in, if you haven't set your own options. So if your default pager is `less` and you don't use `--no-pager` and don't override the options, and you run `git log` without piping it, it will be piped to `less` with Git's defaults, which will retain color-setting escapes.

Comment: Note that Git itself can be told to *always* output color escapes, or *never* output them, or to print them conditioned on whether the output device is a "tty" (`isatty` in the C library says "yes") or not. The default is `auto` which is the test-for-tty mode. It sounds like you have `log.decorate` set to `auto` as well, which is the default since about Git 2.9 or so.